# Getting selected Items from a ListView | CheckBoxListCell

Tags: java, listview, javafx, listviewitem

I want to create a simple `ListView` with `CheckBox` for each item. This has been done. Now I am looking for a way to get all selected Items from this ListView.

I have figured out that I can use the method `setCellFactory()` to add items when they are selected in a separate Collection and remove them when they are unselected. But I think this is an ugly way to do that.

```
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
    String[] toppings = {"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"};
    listView.getItems().addAll(toppings);
    listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(String item) {
        BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        observable.addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected)
            -> System.out.println("Check box for " + item + " changed from " + wasSelected + " to " + isNowSelected)
        );
        return observable;
        }
}));
```

How can I get the list of selected items from the `ListView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this way

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
            Button button = new Button("Get");
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String[] toppings = { "Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives" };
            listView.getItems().addAll(toppings);
            listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(String item) {
                    BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
                    observable.addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                        if (isNowSelected) {
                            list.add(item);
                        } else {
                            list.remove(item);
                        }
                    });
                    return observable;
                }
            }));

            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(list.get(i));
                }
            });

            VBox root = new VBox();
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            root.getChildren().addAll(listView, button);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add a boolean property to your model class, e.g.:

```
public class Topping {

    private final String name ;

    private final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return selected ;
    }

    public final boolean isSelected() {
        return selectedProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        selectedProperty().set(selected);
    }

    public Topping(String name) {
        this.name = name ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName(); 
    }
}
```

and use it in the check box list cell:

```
listView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(Topping::selectedProperty));
```

then you can just create a filtered list which contains all the selected toppings:

```
ListView<Topping> listView = new ListView<>();
listView.getItems().addAll(new Topping("Cheese"), new Topping("Pepperoni"),
    new Topping("Black Olives"));

ObservableList<Topping> selectedToppings = 
    listView.getItems().filtered(Topping::isSelected);
```

Now `selectedToppings` will always contain exactly the toppings that have their check boxes checked in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `selected` property is a part of your model you are now blending a user interaction need with your model, which I would try to avoid.

For example, if you would create two lists where you move the items from one or the other, would you still use this property or would be containment in that list be enough for you?

In your (Pizza?) example an order for once confirmed to the user should only contain toppings that are selected, it would be a strange model if your pizza order would contain all possible toppings and the kitchen would have to iterate over the list in order to find the needed toppings. This is a strong indication that the fact that it is selected is not part of the model but a user interaction item.

To avoid mixing user interface and model you could use the [CheckListView](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/CheckListView.html) of the [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) library which has a `CheckModel` which not only allowes you to query the checked items, but also manipulate it if your logic would require to do so.